# Как вставить 700 строк в таблицу?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как вставить 700 строк в таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE numb(
  key integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
  tstamp timestamptz NOT NULL,
  val FLOAT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "numb_key" PRIMARY KEY (key),
  FOREIGN KEY (key) REFERENCES tableglo(key));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для заполнения таблицы данными можете использовать функцию `generate_series`

```
INSERT INTO numb (tstamp, val) 
select NOW(), number from generate_series(0,699) number;
```